# Test Method Issue for removing duplicates from List

Tags: apex, code-coverage, list, sobject, failing-tests

I have a requirement to remove the duplicate objects from a list at several places in my integration code and I have developed a method in the Util class to remove the duplicate objects from the list. The code in the Util.cls is below.

```
public static List<SObject> removeDuplicatesFromList(List<SObject> lstSObjects) {
    return new List<SObject>(new Set<SObject>(lstSObjects));
}
```

Below is my test method in the TestUtil class.

```
static void testMethod testRemoveDuplicatesFromList() {
    Test.startTest();
    List<String> strList = new List<String>{'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'jkl'};
    List<String> resultStrList = Util.removeDuplicatesFromList(strList);
    System.assertEquals(4, resultStrList.size());
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

However, I am unable to save the TestUtil class with the above test method and I am getting the below error.

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void removeDuplicatesFromList(List) from the type Util.
```

The Util class has the method definition to return a List, but the error message shows a method with void return type does not exist.

Can someone help and let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Hi @Balaji, The signature of the method is to accept List<Sobjects>, But you are passing the list <String>. Can you try passing List<Sobject> to the method.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the method is to accept `List<Sobjects>`, But you are passing the `list <String>`. Can you try passing `List<Sobject>` to the method.